# How to use roxygen2 to print documentation of self defined function?

Tags: r, documentation-generation, roxygen2

I define a function called avglist in R and would like to print the documentation of avglist using ?avglist or help(avglist), but they both failed.

```
library(roxygen2)

#' Function:avglist
#' 
#' Calculate the average of numbers within a range
#' 
#' This function computes the average of all numbers in a list that within
#' a specified range
#' 
#' @param lst A list of numeric values
#' @param low The lower bound of the range (exclusive)
#' @param high The upper bound of the range (exclusive)
#' 
#' @return The average of numbers within the specified range
#' @export
#' 
avglist <- function(lst,low=0,high=100) {
  filtered_values <- lst[lst > low & lst < high]
  mean(filtered_values)
}
```

when I run the code, system showed this:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAJGH.png)

And when I tried ??avglist, it showed this:
[help screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn9FI.png)

Does anyone know how to print out the documentation of avglist?

Comment: Did you run `roxygenate` to actually generate the help files?

Comment: Documentation only works for functions defined within packages. Is your function defined in a package? Are you using `devtools` to load the function? Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064), it's better to include text in the question itself so errors are searchable in the future.

Comment: @MrFlick research what roxygen2 is for

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover From the [roxygen2 website](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/): "... describe your functions in comments next to their definitions and roxygen2 will process your source code and comments to automatically generate .Rd files in man/, NAMESPACE, and, if needed, the Collate field in DESCRIPTION." The package makes it easy to create Rd files which are the documentation files for R packages. You can't use Rd files if you don't have a package. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338044/can-roxygen-really-document-r-script-not-a-package-just-like-doxygen-does-for

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for your advice. I'm new here so don't know it's better not to post code in images, would definitely include text next time.

Comment: I try roxygenate and devtools but both show error.